# RVIs and routing out of firewall

Tags: vlan, firewall, juniper-junos, layer3, juniper-ex

I have managed to configure a number of EX3300 switches (using virtual chassis) with vlans and the appropriate layer-3 configurations for RVIs.

I can get the traffic to flow internally on the switches, however, I'm having difficulties get traffic to go out of the firewall in a way I would like.

Currently, I have been able to set up a trunk port that sends traffic through the firewall but I have to set the firewall as the default gateway. If I'm not mistaken, in this scenario the firewall is actually doing the routing.

My thought is to create another vlan to connect to the firewall with a regular access port. But I'm not sure how to route the traffic out of my RVIs through the new vlan.

Am I going in the right direction? What am I missing? I feel like it's something relatively simple.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a L3 interface and route over that interface to the firewall using a routing protocol or static routes.

```
interface ge-0/0/2 {
    unit 0 {
        family inet {
            address 192.0.2.1/30;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I route over the new interface? What routing protocol would I use? Or, what static routes, one for each of the other L3 interfaces?

set routing-options static route 192.168.5.0/24 next-hop 172.16.1.2 something like this?

Comment: As, a follow up to my previous comment/questions. I also, have a point to point VPN to another location through the firewall. Do I need to do anything special to route back into my other L3 interfaces?

Comment: These questions are too broad. I would humbly suggest learning more about routing in general, as this will answer all of your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your time and pointing me in the right direction.